# Sticky doesn't work with flexbox. How can I fix it avoiding giving a height to parent container?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-position, sticky

I have a parent container which has following styles:

```
.container{
   display: flex; 
   justify-content: space-between; 
   align-items:start;
}
```

And I have two children divs and one of them should be sticky when user scrolls. It has following styles:

```
.div2 {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    height: 100dvh;
    align-self: flex-start;
}
```

The thing is that `div2` when user scrolls doesn't stick. And it stays in the same position.

I tried giving `align-items:start;` to `container` div and `height: 100dvh;` to `div2` but it didn't help.

Giving a height to parent container doesn't solve the problem that I want. If the parent container has a height and `overflow:auto` it will look not so good.

BTW, body has this style but not sure if it is related to issue:

`overflow-x: hidden;`

Comment: You have to give height to parent container

Comment: but what if the parent container shouldn't have height?